# how to druid metadata storage replication and clustering

Tags: replication, derby, druid

I am using derbydb as metastorage. However, I'm unable to find any material that either explains it in a decent fashion or is able to convince me that replication doesn't exist for Derby.

Comment: Can you please specify what you wish to learn about Derby?

https://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/

Comment: Do you know any other derby replication guides? 
This site https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/adminguide/cadminreplication.html lacks information